# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

We are seeing below issue while analyzing the PR, even we are not spinning any version in the pom file and its failing while analyzing the code.

Even after removing the plugin version its the same issue. Can you please help with this.

Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project amap-repo: PUT https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/m/amap-common-lib/pullrequests/175/comments/130003966 
returned a response status of 404 Not Found ->

> [Help 1] 14:22:15
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project amap-repo: PUT
>   https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/mediaiq/amap-common-lib/pullrequests/175/comments/130003966
>   returned a response status of 404 Not Found 14:22:15 at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>   14:22:15 at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)

Comment: Have you tried changing the version?

Comment: @VishwaRatna Yes , before we had hardcoded the maven plugin version in pom file, later we have removed it  as it will take latest version automatically ,but with latest version also same issue. This issue we are facing post sonar upgrade from 7.1 to 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command to archive your issue. I was facing the same but below command worked.

`- mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:Port -Dsonar.login=Token -Dsonar.login=Sonar_username -Dsonar.password=Sonar_password`